# How to use subxt to execute a utility.batch call?

Tags: subxt

So far the team was aiming for doing something like this:

```
let batch_tx = subxt::dynamic::tx(
    "Utility",
    "batch",
    txes.iter().map(|tx| tx.into_value()).collect::<Vec<Value<_>>>(),
);
```

Comment: There is an example of creating a dynamic transaction [here](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/8484c18624783af36476fc5bf6a0f08d5363a3db/examples/examples/dynamic_multisig.rs#L37-L75) - it is a multisig example but still helpful - it uses a nested call just like batch does.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```rust
let tx = polkadot::tx()
         .utility()
         .batch(calls);

let hash = api.tx().sign_and_submit_default(&tx, &signer).await?;

println!("Extrinsic submitted: {}", hash);

Ok(())
```

where `calls` is a `vec!` of calls.